# Are there any websites providing movies recommendations based on your ratings?

Tags: webapp-rec

You rate films you've watched and get recommendations on new movies based on other people rates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [TasteKid](http://www.tastekid.com/) or [Jinni](http://www.jinni.com/).

**EDIT:** Lifehacker has just posted [a top 5 movie recommendation services](http://lifehacker.com/5884202/five-best-movie-recommendation-services).

Answer (score 1):

[Netflix](http://www.netflix.com)'s movie recommendation engine works that way.

Comment: nice one but it doesn't work in every country (for instance, it doesn't work in France without a workaround)

Answer (score 0):

[Filmaster.com](http://filmaster.org/display/DEV/API) has an open api. You can go directly to the main page by [clicking here](http://filmaster.org/display/DEV/API).

Comment: Can you explain how this helps? Don't forget we're talking about **users** of web applications here, not **developers**.